# Why my media queries don't work?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, flexbox, responsive

I made a page with code from [Moving from HTML Grid Systems to CSS Grid Systems](http://zellwk.com/blog/from-html-grids-to-css-grids/). But my page doesn't work as it has to, media queries seem to be not working. Why don't they work? CSS lint says there are some problems [CSS Lint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLfh7.png)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> -->
  <title>Flex-training</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="l-flex">
    <div id="back" class="l-fg3">
      <div>Featured Item</div>
      <div>Featured Item</div>
      <div>Grid item</div>
      <div>Grid item</div>
      <div>Grid item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.l-fg3 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -10px;
}

.l-fg3 > div {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
          flex-basis: 100%;
  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-flex-basis: calc(33.333%-20px);
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: calc(33.333%-20px);
            flex-basis: calc(33.333%-20px);
  }

  > div:nth-child(1),
  > div:nth-child(2) {
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
    }
  }
}

.l-flex {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


div {
  border: 0.2px solid #506183;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #81f6a9;
}
#back {
  background-color: #36a4c3
}
```

Comment: This looks like Sass (SCSS) rather than CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Media queries contain selectors groups, not the other way around.

You need to modify your CSS like so:

```css
.l-fg3 > div {
    ...
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .l-fg3 > div {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right but I think the main issue is that the OP has posted SCSS not CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This is [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/). It looks like it works once compiled to CSS:

(Also, you need to put a space between the values in your `calc()` functions.)

```css
.l-fg3 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -10px;
}

.l-fg3 > div {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .l-fg3 > div {
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 20px);
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: calc(33.333% - 20px);
    flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 20px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .l-fg3 > div > div:nth-child(1),
  .l-fg3 > div > div:nth-child(2) {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
}

.l-flex {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

div {
  border: 0.2px solid #506183;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #81f6a9;
}

#back {
  background-color: #36a4c3;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-flex">
    <div id="back" class="l-fg3">
      <div>Featured Item</div>
      <div>Featured Item</div>
      <div>Grid item</div>
      <div>Grid item</div>
      <div>Grid item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've put it as a codepen so you can toggle between pre-processed (less/sass/etc) and vanilla CSS:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMJqOz

Comment: Okay, I got you.
Now I have another problem:
@ media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .l-fg3 > div {
        margin: 10px;
        flex-basis: 31%;
    }
}
@ media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .featured {
        flex-basis: 43%;
    }
}
My featured divs don't want to be 43%, they stay the same - 31% . How can I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like a case of [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The two selectors are competing and in this case the first one trumps the second. Try being more *specific* with your selector, eg: `.l-fg3 > div.featured { flex-basis: 43%; }`

Answer (score 0):

When you have errors in a CSS block, the entire block will stop processing. The CSS Lint is telling you exactly what the problems are. For example:

```
> div:nth-child(1),
> div:nth-child(2)
```